# Conference Call using adb shell

Tags: calls

I am trying to automate a conference call in android. So far I have been able to automate making a call and receiving a call. I use the following command to make a call

```
adb -s <serial no> shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL -d tel:<telephone_no>
```

And then I query the other phone that is connected to adb server by this command

```
adb -s <serial no> shell dumpsys telephony.registry | grep "mCallState"
```

for windows

```
adb -s <serial no> shell dumpsys telephony.registry | findstr "mCallState"
```

based on the call state I can accept the call by

```
adb -s <serial no> shell input keyevent 5
```

and reject the call by

```
adb -s <serial no> shell input keyevent 6
```

Now if I want to make a conference call, I have to hold the call then dial again and on receive I will have to merge the call.
I have used **KEYCODE_BREAK** as I found it as the break and pause button from the page [android keyevent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html)

I also need the merge button key map.

thanks in advance.